# Mathematics operations in phpmaker

Tags: php

Can I know how to do mathematics operations like $x = "x2" _ "x1"; but for tables in ️ phpmaker ️?**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a phpmaker is and I think it's more comfortable without such things but I don't know too much what you mean but this comes to mind

```
<?php $x = $x2-$x1;  echo $x  ?>
```

or use / to divide